# Can I get some help identifying this figurine of a blonde swordswoman wearing a highleg?

Tags: merchandise

[image: Blonde swordswoman wearing a highleg]

My daughter bought this at a garage sale, but we do not know who she is. I do not know many anime series and I have not found a match using Google image search. Can someone give me the name and the series that she is from? Thanks.

Comment: Are there any manufacturer's marks, or any markings at all?  Is the figure poseable?  Are there pegs or slots for a stand/base (/did it come with one)?  Are any of the parts detachable (ie, the face on some figures can be swapped for others).  Are the sword and gun removable, can we get better shots of them (especially the flat of the sword)?  What hairstyle does she have?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know this would be so complicated... to answer your questions. No there are o manufacturers marks,or markings at all, figures arms move at the shoulders only, there is no base it did not come with one,or slots for a base to go in, no parts are detachable. I'll take some better photos  and post them,.

Answer (score 10):

She is [Yuna Kagurazaka](http://myanimelist.net/character/5488/Yuna_Kagurazaka) from [Galaxy Fraulein Yuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galaxy_Fraulein_Yuna), which is a series of video games that also spawned two OVA releases.

[image: Yuna in the OVA]

You can find the same figurine in different angles [here](http://www.collectiondx.com/toy_review/1998/galaxy_fraulein_yuna).

[image: Yuna as a figurine]